# How to extract email ids from a data frame column and send mail automatically using R

Tags: r, rdcomclient

I am using the RDCOMClient library to automate outlook mails from R. Now the count of recipients' mail id changes periodically. Is there any way to automatically access the ** Email ID ** column in a data frame, say df, and send mail automatically?

Below is the existing code with static 2 recipients.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]]=paste("abc@xyz.com","kksk@xyz.com", collapse=NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it sounds easy enough. Consider the following Dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(emails = c("abc@xyz.com","kksk@xyz.com", 'yyz@tup.org'))
recipients <- df$emails
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]]=paste(recipients)
recipients
```

Comment: I receive error as    checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred